# isLoggedIn() method is not working,I have been trying this code but it's helpless

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

```
  function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){  // middleware
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next();
        }
        res.redirect("/login");
        console.log("It's not working");
    }

   app.get("/campgrounds/:id/comments/new", isLoggedIn ,function(req,res){
   Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, campground){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
   }else{
        res.render("comments/new.ejs",{campground:campground});
        console.log("It's working")
   }
   }); 
});


    app.post("/campgrounds/:id/comments", isLoggedIn , function(req,res){
   Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err,campground){
        if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/campgrounds");
    }else{
        Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err,comment){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                campground.comments.push(comment);
                campground.save();
                res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
            }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Whenever I am trying to add a comment with user logged in, it's showing me the error "It's not working" as per the console.log here. Please help

Comment: so, the unseen code that is `req.isAuthenticated()` returns `false`

Comment: yes @JaromandaX, it's going to the login page but i want it to edit the comments and save it

Comment: so, *why* is `req.isAuthenticated()` returning false? i.e. you've `passport.js` - perhaps the problem is in how you are using `passport.js` ... Local? Oauth? OpenId? Facebook? Google? Twitter? etc

Comment: local @JaromandaX

Comment: clearly your authentication implementation (still not actually shown) is wrong

Answer (score 0):

check the call isLoggedIn call back and be sure it's written correctly

```
function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next()
        }
        res.redirect("/login")
     }
```